# JPA findBy trying to get data based on Entity Column name instead of liquibase Column name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

```
    select
        emaillimit0_.id as id1_1_,
        emaillimit0_.maxEmailLmt as maxEmail2_1_,
        emaillimit0_.rmngEmailLmt as rmngEmai3_1_,
        emaillimit0_.usrNm as usrNm4_1_ 
    from
        email_limit emaillimit0_ 
    where
        emaillimit0_.usrNm=?

2020-08-28 12:49:09.958 ERROR 9100 --- [nio-8090-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : ERROR: column emaillimit0_.maxemaillmt does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "emaillimit0_.maxEmailLmt".
  Position: 35
```

I have configured liquibase for easy DB migration in my spring boot project. And, the tables are created in the DB based on liquibase changelog which is correct. But, when there is a JPA call or save then the Entity column name takes place instead of liquibase column names.

Could you pls anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to map your column using @Column on field.

Comment: Please provide your `Entity class`

Comment: @Rono, Is that mandatory to maintain both column names in Entity and liquibase as same? Bcoz, it works only when all the "@Column" name and liquibase table column name in lowercase.

Comment: @SSK, Below is my **EntityClass**                                                                `@Entity
@Table(name = "email_limit")
public class EmailLimit {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id")
 private long id;
 
 @Column(name="usrnm")
 private String usrNm;
 
 @Column(name="maxemaillmt")
 private Integer maxEmailLmt;
 
 @Column(name="rmngemaillmt")
 private Integer rmngEmailLmt;`

Comment: And my liquibase table is,
```<createTable tableName="email_limit">
<column name="id" type="bigserial" autoIncrement="true">
<constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
</column>
<column name="usrnm" type="varchar(128)">
<constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
</column>
<column name="maxemaillmt" type="bigserial">
<constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
<column name="rmngemaillmt" type="bigserial">
<constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
</createTable>```

Comment: Yes @Column's name and liquibase name should be same

Comment: Thanks @Rono . But, Even though both liquibase and entity "@Column" name are the same. It works only if the column names are in lower case. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: When query generated it quote not added in column name  so `firstName` and `firstname` is same, use extra quote like `@Column(name = "\"firstName\""` or change hibernate quote setting true `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`.